# Logo image getting cut off when browsing mobile or making browser smaller - CSS/Flexbox Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to the world of HTML/CSS and currently working through an online course. I've been working on one of my projects for a few hours and am absolutely stumped with an issue with my navigation bar.

The logo and nav links display fine on a desktop browser; however, when you make the browser the minimum size or browse on a mobile, the logo image is cut off on the right-hand side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');   

.top-bar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  align-items: top;
}

.header-img {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 534px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-bar { 
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.nav-bar a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #808080;
}

.nav-bar a:last-of-type {
  border: none;
}

#home { 
    flex-basis: 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 }

#features {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#video {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#pricing {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
   <title>Eltee's Electric Drums</title>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto">
   <div class="top-bar">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KCS3KND.png" id="header-img" class="header-img"></img>
   <nav class="nav-bar" id="nav-bar">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#home" id="home">Home</a>
     <a class="nav-link" href="#features" id="features">Features</a>
     <a class="nav-link" href="#video" id="video">Video</a>
     <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing" id="pricing">Pricing</a>
   </nav> 
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed a media query to deal with mobile viewport.  I've added to your script as  `.top-bar img`.  Also your markup was located in the incorrect spot.  `<style>` tag lives inside `<head>` and following `</head>` you need `body` tag and inside body tag is where your markup lives.  so it should go as follows `<html><head><style>css lives here</style></head><body>markup lives here</body></html>`

See snippet for working solution, though it will likely only show the mobile solution given the snippet editor dimensions, so ingest the markup and styling into your page and it should works as expected for both mobile and desktop.

```css
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

    .top-bar {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #ECECEC;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      align-items: top;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .top-bar img {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    }

    .header-img {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 534px;
      height: auto;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }

 

    .nav-bar {
      display: flex;
      flex: 2;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    }

    .nav-bar a {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }

    .nav-bar a:hover {
      color: #808080;
    }

    .nav-bar a:last-of-type {
      border: none;
    }

    #home {
      flex-basis: 20%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #features {
      display: flex;
      flex-basis: 20%;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #video {
      display: flex;
      flex-basis: 20%;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #pricing {
      display: flex;
      flex-basis: 20%;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    body {
      padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <title>Eltee's Electric Drums</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KCS3KND.png" id="header-img" class="header-img"/>
      <nav class="nav-bar" id="nav-bar">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home" id="home">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#features" id="features">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#video" id="video">Video</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing" id="pricing">Pricing</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Authentic-Science that worked perfectly and I actually needed to use a media query to satisfy the requirements of this project. I also appreciate the other advice regarding the HTML layout.

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck on the course.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your logo inside a `div` that would shrink and grow as a flex item. And tell the logo to fit the `div`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');   

.top-bar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  align-items: top;
}

.header-img {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 534px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.header-img img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.nav-bar { 
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.nav-bar a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #808080;
}

.nav-bar a:last-of-type {
  border: none;
}

#home { 
    flex-basis: 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 }

#features {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#video {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#pricing {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
 }
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <title>Eltee's Electric Drums</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto">
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="header-img"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KCS3KND.png" id="header-img" ></img></div>
    <nav class="nav-bar" id="nav-bar">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home" id="home">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#features" id="features">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#video" id="video">Video</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing" id="pricing">Pricing</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```